# Configure which spotlight attributes to show in Finder preview?

Tags: macos, mac, finder, spotlight, attributes

Is it possible to configure which attributes to show for file in Finder column view?

For all files Name, Kind, Size, Created, Modified and Last opened are shown, but for apps there is also Version, for videos — Dimensions and Duration, for audio files — Duration and Audio bit rate. So is it possible to configure what to show there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no. You can modify slightly for the list view, but not for the column view. The extra attributes (eg. Dimensions for Video or Image files) are read by Spotlight as metadata and show as necessary for different file types. You can run `mdls` on the command line to see all the metadata associated with a file.

Comment: Sad to hear, it would be useful to show there for example tags assigned with OpenMeta or other comments